# What will be final velocity of three charges $q$, $q$, $2q$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics

What will be final velocity of three charges q, q and 2q kept along an equilateral triangle of side r at infinite distance.
All three masses are equal.

[image]
I tried to conserve Total Energy

$$\frac{2kq^2}{r} + \frac{2kq^2}{r} + \frac{kq^2}{r} = \frac{mv^2}{2}+ \frac{mv^2}{2} + \frac{m(v_{2})^2}{2})$$

$$\frac{5kq^2}{r} = m(v^2 + \frac{v_{2}^2}{2}$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{10kq^2}{rm}-2v^2}= v_{2}$$

Conserving momentum gave

$$v_{2} = v\sqrt{2(1+\cos\theta)}\tag{1}$$
where $\theta$ is angle b\w velocity of q & q.

When I tried to make some graph predicting their motion and speed in different direction was like hell.

I could not get any further.

As helped by Fire I used COM along y direction.

$$my + my - my' = 0$$
$$ y' = 2y$$
$$dy'/dt = 2dy/dt $$
$$ v_{2}= 2 v_{y}$$
$$v_{2}= 2 v\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\tag{2}$$

I can't imagine if charges would move along straight line or in curves. Will $\theta$ change or not? Can all three have same velocity at infinity?

Someone told me it uses Taylor series.

Comment: I take back the previous comment. The constraint is absolutely critical in this, and if you are going to use any kind of conservation it tells you things not clearly specified in the problem statement. This may be a very cute (i.e. deeply evil) exercise.

Comment: I guess some information on the masses is needed.

Comment: as dmckee said, it is likely to be an evil problem. I just tried writing the equation of motion for the q-particles and solve it numerically. Interestingly, their orbits look optically very much linear (!?). But maybe it is just an error in coding, I did not have time to check the detail carefully, though.

Comment: Are you looking for the shape of the triangle as time goes to infinity, or the exact trajectories of the particles? Because the shape of the triangle might be reasonably easily calculable, while the exact trajectories of the particles are going to be horrible.

Comment: @PeterShor, I have a written a solution below that seems right, but there's something I can't prove. Is there a way to show that the shape of the triangle actually converges at infinity?

Comment: I find odd that @David Z closed this question as off-topic. It sounds like a homework, but it is rather non-trivially interesting. The questioner did show effort in solving it, too.

Comment: @Peter Shor : I just need final velocity at infinity.
That may( I'm not sure) need final angle. If final angle is not constant, may be I need something to remove $\theta$.

Comment: @ophelia Being nontrivially interesting is not one of the criteria we use to determine whether a question is on topic or not. Hopefully you find it less odd after noting that. If you think the question does not meet the criteria for being on hold, you can make _that_ argument for reopening it. But as I see it, the question is homework-like and does not ask a conceptual question - what it's asking is basically "what do I do next?"

Comment: @DavidZ thanks for answering, I misunderstood the purpose of PSE (only conceptual questions). I think that may be rather narrow; sometimes one just cannot distinguish conceptual-like problems and calculation-like problems. That is what I have seen in mathoverflow. Anyway I really do not want to go into such kind of discussions; let it closed.

Answer (score 2):

It might help you to think about the symmetry of the situation.

[image]

First in the application of conservation of momentum and then what the trajectories of the charges must be to keep the centre of mass $C$ at the same position.  This will give you a connection between $v_y$ and $v_x$.

Comment: I already had that figure in mind but couldn't get connection b/w vx and vy

Comment: What **must** happen to the three masses if the centre of mass stays in the same position?  Move just one of of the masses and note the effect on the position of the centre of mass.  Do the same for two masses.

Comment: Sorry!! but still got nothing

Comment: @AnubhavGoel - Farcher's answer is correct...

Comment: @honeste_vivere He is always correct. But hint is not getting me anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a more general case in which the three charges are $\lambda q, q$, and $q$, with $\lambda\geq 0$. Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be the respective positions of the charges. By symmetry, we have $|AB|=|AC|$. Due to the conservation of momentum, the center of mass $O$ of the system is stationary.

Let $\theta$ be the angle $OBC$, and $\alpha$ be the angle $ABO$. Simple trigonometric manipulations give the relation

$$\tan\alpha=\frac{2\tan\theta}{3\tan^2\theta+1}.$$

Notice that $\theta=\alpha=\pi/6$ at $t=0$.

Now, consider the forces $\mathbf F_{AB}$ and $\mathbf F_{CB}$ on charge $B$ by charges $A$ and $C$, respectively. The angle $\theta$ changes when $\mathbf F_{AB} + \mathbf F_{CB}$ is not solely along $OB$. So, as $t\rightarrow\infty$, we expect $\theta$ to approach a constant value $\theta_\infty$, such that $\mathbf F_{AB} + \mathbf F_{CB}$ is solely along $OB$. That is, $\theta_\infty$ satisfies

$$F_{AB} \sin\alpha_\infty =  F_{CB}\sin\theta_\infty.$$

Using the form of the Coulomb's law for $F_{AB}$ and $F_{CB}$, we find that

$$4\lambda\sin\alpha_\infty=\sin\theta_\infty(1+9\tan^2\theta_\infty),$$

which then allows us to solve for $\theta_\infty$.

Finally, with the relative positions of the charges known, the conservation of energy easily yields the final velocities of the three charges.

Lastly, for $\lambda\ll1$ and $\lambda\gg1$, we see that $\theta_\infty=0$ and $\theta_\infty=\pi/2$, respectively. For the specific case of $\lambda=2$, we can numerically obtain $\theta_\infty\approx0.657$.

Comment: As t→∞, the angle theta approaches a
constant value theta∞. This means that the
resultant force acting on the charge at B is
solely along OB . I did not understand how resultant force is solely along OB.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel, if the force is not along $OB$, the angle $\theta$ would change.

Comment: Why force is along OB at infinity.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel, if the force is not along $OB$ at $t\rightarrow\infty$, the angle $\theta$ would not be a constant.

Comment: By saying OB here do you mean B at infinity or B when it is in equilateral triangle.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel, when $B$ is in the equilateral triangle, the force is not along $OB$, because of the unequal charges. This causes $\theta$ to change, until $t\rightarrow\infty$ when the force is along $OB$.

Comment: I think your comment should not be correct. You did not even use the detail of the coulomb law, which means that the conclusion is true for any system with any kind of force. Suppose the big charge is zero instead of 2q, the conclusion is still true. But it apparently wrong because the force at any time is along BC, and does not pass O.

Comment: @leongz If force at ∞ is along OB than theta should be π/6. But in next line you give theta 0.79

Comment: @ophelia, I have included more details in my answer. Note that the numerical result has been corrected. Let me know if you still think something is incorrect.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel, $\theta$ is $\pi/6$ at $t=0$. When $B$ moves, $\theta$ changes.

Comment: @leongz I think there are still multiple problems. "1) Consider a more general case in which the three charges are λq,q, and q, with λ≥0. Let A, B, and C be the respective positions of the charges. By symmetry, we have |AB|=|BC|." Are you sure about the symbols; by symmetry, only AB=AC. "The angle θ changes when FAB+FCB is not solely along OB. " this is also likely not correct. The angle change not because of the force, by because of the velocity. Given a fixed geometry of ABC, the forces are fixed, but the configuration in the next time depends only on v_B, v_C.

Comment: @ophelia, your first point is a typo, which I have fixed. Your second point is valid. I believe what I need to show is that $\theta$ actually converges at infinity.

Comment: $$\tan\alpha=\frac{2\tan\theta}{3\tan^2\theta+1}.$$  How to take it out.

Comment: @leongz, I think it would be quite easy to show that theta converges to something. But it does not follow that FAB+FCB is along OB. Further, if $AB \ne BC$ (the typo), then your second equation will not imply your third equation. To be honest, I think your idea won't work.

Comment: @leongz : You mean to say final force is along OB but velocity is at an angle 0.657.

Comment: @leongz : I like your approach, but I, too, think there's an issue with it. It's nice to be able to approximate long-term effects, but I don't think it's fair to do so in this way. The difficulty is that assuming the force lies strictly along OB presumes that either the charges are equal, or that B is the asymetric charge. Now, we do have an asymmetric charge to deal with, but if that's what we're dealing with, then making this assumption isn't an assumption at all, and doesn't add anything new.

Comment: $4\lambda\sin\alpha_\infty=\sin\theta_\infty(1+9\tan^2\theta_\infty),$ I don't get its derivation.

Answer (score 1):

You're only a half-step away. You listed conservation of energy and linear momentum, both of which are due to there being no external forces on the three-charge system. But with no external forces, you know that the center of mass of the system won't accelerate. Since the COM starts at rest, this means that the COM will remain stationary. Think about what this means in terms of the geometry of your problem.

(I'll help you out with this if you don't see it, but I think you will.)

Comment: Still struck. Please help!

Comment: The system of three particles has a center of mass at the center of the triangle, right? Well, if one particle moves radially outward by 1 cm, then the other two must do the same, or else the center of mass of the system moves, and we know that it can't.

The big point is that you already have the final angles between the particles because you have the initial angles. Do you see it?

Comment: Why the rest two charges would also move 1 cm?

Comment: Consider in above diagram 2q moves upward by 2 cm. Then , q moves down by 1 cm. qmay move let by 1 or 2 or 3 cm. Center of mass remain at same position.

Comment: sorry! not let , left by 1, 2 or 3cm.

Comment: If you set your coordinate system so that the origin is at the center of the triangle, then the angle from the horizontal to either of the lower two charges is $30^\circ$. When the top charge moves upward by 2cm, the lower two charges move 2cm outward along the lines connecting them to the origin. So the angles between the charges remain exactly the same as they initially are.

This means that you have only two unknowns: $v$ and $v_2$. And you have two equations, so you're set to go.

Comment: Which angle is 30°?

Comment: and also what did leongz took at as $\theta ∞ = 0.79$

Comment: I'm sorry, Anubhav. I think leongz may have been correct. In reworking the problem, it becomes obvious that $\theta$ *does* change, so I'll look again in a moment (I'm at work at the mo).

I like your conservation of energy and conservation of linear momentum, but I want to look at which other quantities may be conserved in your instance. Angular momentum would be a pain to work with, as both v and r change with time, but I'm sure there's something simple missing. This shouldn't be some outrageous problem, and I'm sure it's not.

Comment: @Fire, I have updated my solution, but it isn't particularly neat. Do let me know if you find something simpler.

Comment: I've tried approaching this a couple different ways, but it seems that circumstance is against me, and I can't keep one train of thought going long without interruption. Here are the two approaches I was thinking of:

1. Replace the two charges at the bottom with a single charge that has double the mass and double the charge (M=2m, Q=2q), though you'd have to adjust the position accordingly to somewhere on the y-axis. This would give you a way to solve for $v_y (final)$ for the charge at the top of the triangle, and from there, you could solve for the remaining variables.

Comment: I'm not sure how messy that would become, though, but it feels like a reasonable approach. From there, it should be pretty easy to combine conservation of momentum and energy, which is what your equations currently do. Your values would change just a bit, and your angle would be set to $0^\circ$ (or maybe it's $90^\circ$, depending on how you're defining your angle). Like I said, I haven't been able to play with this much, and I'm very sorry for the slow responses, but thought I'd give you what I wanted to try, at least.

Comment: How do I know solution works for 3 body system too, where angles are included.

Comment: Using your method I got $v = \sqrt{\frac{8kq^2}{3am}}$ for 2q

Comment: It gave me v for 2m charge also. I applied $v_{2}$ to obtain v of individual q also.

Comment: But how do I know it is same as three body consideration.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a particular case of the three-body problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem), but with repulsion, rather than attraction. There are very few exactly solvable cases of the three-body problem, among them - the Lagrange's case, where the three bodies are at the vertexes of an equilateral triangle at each moment. Therefore, I suspect you should try to prove for the initial conditions of your problem that the distances between the charges remain equal (although I cannot be sure that this is so). Some homework...

Comment: how would I know if distances b/w them remain same?

Comment: It does not look like they do, so my suggestion looks wrong.